# Current implementations of redis HA / cluster for a production environment

Tags: redis, high-availability, consistency

I'm struggling to find up-to-date information on the state of redis HA / clustering for production environments.

From what I can tell redis-cluster is work in progress, as is sentinel. It appears to have been like this for quite a while now?

For a production system that requires high availability and consistency, what are my current options, if any?

At the moment I'm leaning towards a simple keepalived solution by promoting slaves to master, but I'm not 100% confident it will handle consistency well.

Answer (score -1):

Redis HA/clustering has been in development for years. For high availability and consistency, you can try MongoDB, Cassadra, or HBase.

Comment: Unfortunately we're stuck with redis (or possibly RabbitMQ).